# Open and search Documentation-Center

Tags: documentation

In notebooks you can press <kbd>F1</kbd> (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> for a new window) to:

1. **open** the help page of the marked `Symbol` or the `Symbol` under the cursor in the Documentation Center
2. to **search** the Documentation Center, if no direct page was available

**Question:** Is it possible to achieve exactly this behavior with a function `searchDoc[input_String]`?

### Related issues

**Related 1:**
As stated in the documentation to `Hyperlink`, this here opens the documentation of `Plot` in a new window

```
NotebookOpen["paclet:/ref/Plot"]
```

but if the "paclet" does not exist, an error message appears instead of a search in the docs.

**Related 2:** It's possible to mimic the behavior of <kbd>F1</kbd> with a `FrontEndToken`.

```
Button["HEEELP!!", FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["SelectionHelpDialog"]]]
```

This button shows the help of marked symbols or of symbols under the cursor. Problem here is, that it searches always the selected expression. Maybe there exists something similar which can take an input string.

**Related 3:** One of the probably biggest resource of information can be found in package

```
$InstallationDirectory/AddOns/Applications/DocumentationSearch
```

This seems to contain the functions and helpers which are actually used in the Documentation Center. See for instance what

```
DocumentationSearch`SearchDocumentation["Graphics"]
```

gives.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `` Documentation`HelpLookup["some input"] ``. This is the function that is executed when you hit F1 (after the front end figures out what is under the cursor).

Comment: Awesome!! Exactly what I was looking for.