# How can I open the Documentation Center window with FrontEndTokenExecute?

Tags: front-end

`FrontEndTokenExecute["Save"]` saves the current notebook, but `FrontEndTokenExecute["Wolfram Documentation"]` does not open the documentation notebook. Why?

Comment: try `FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenHelpLink"]`?

Comment: To explain @kglr's comment, these `FrontEndToken` objects actually reference a special set of token functions the FE provides. You can see them in ``FrontEndExecute@
 FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath["KeyEventTranslations.tr", 
  "PrivatePathsTextResources"]`` and ``FrontEndExecute@
 FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath["MenuSetup.tr", "PrivatePathsTextResources"]``. They do not always have the name provided in the menu.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41725 Also related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16460

Comment: "OpenHelpLink" works for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Working from kglr's and b3m2a1's comments, I will record a CW answer.

The menu tokens are stored in the file `MenuSetup.tr` buried deep within the Mathematica installation. To look at it you can execute the following:

```
SystemOpen[
  FrontEndExecute @
    FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath["MenuSetup.tr", "PrivatePathsTextResources"]]
```

The result will be the desired file appearing in new front-end window. You can then search in it for "Help". which will give you

[image: menu_token]

and thus revealing the token you are looking for.

The above worked for me. I'm running V11.3 on OS X 10.13.4. Alexey Popkov says it didn't work for him. He recommends

```
FilePrint[
  FrontEndExecute @
    FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath["MenuSetup.tr", "PrivatePathsTextResources"]]
```

In this case, the result will be the desired file printed in the current Notebook.

Once again, as in fantasy fiction, knowing something's true name gives power over it.